# CtrlP and Fallback Command

Tags: git, vim

So I have a directory called `dir` in which it has this structure:

```
dir
|-- .git
|-- BUILD.txt
`-- www
    `-- README.txt
```

I open up Vim and set my current working directory to `dir/www`. For some reason, CtrlP doesn't list all files under that directory. I have `['.git', 'cd %s && git ls-files | grep -v "\.\(png\|gif|jp\(e\)\?g\)\$"', 'find %s -type f | grep -v -P "\.jpg$|/tmp/"']` as my `g:ctrlp_user_command` option. Any ideas?

Comment: So… what files are listed and what files are not?

Comment: No files are being listed at all. Also the `README.txt` is a symlink from another directory although I do have `let g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks=1` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for ctrlp_follow_symlinks.

`:help g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks`

> ...
>
> Note: does not apply when a command defined with g:ctrlp_user_command
>   is being used.

Your custom command is at fault for not finding any of the files, and so this is a bash question, not a ctrlp question. :)

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to simply `find %s -type f`. Still doesn't work. I manually did `find  . -type f` in the terminal and that worked so I guess there's something else I'm missing.